# Issue with QlikView Reports Accessibility in WebView

Tags: webview, reporting, user-permissions, qlikview, web-access

I'm encountering an issue related to report visibility in the QlikView Desktop application's WebView.

Problem Description:
I have various reports in the QlikView Desktop application that I can see without any issues. When I view the module in a web browser using my own account, all reports display correctly. However, for some other users, while some reports are visible, others are not.

What I've Tried:

Checked User Permissions: Ensured that all users have the appropriate permissions to view these reports. This seemed logical since different users have varied visibility.

Cleared Browser Cache: Encouraged some of the affected users to clear their browser cache to determine if cached data was causing the inconsistencies. No change was observed post this action.

Reviewed Report Settings in QlikView: Returned to the QlikView Desktop application to verify if any report-specific settings could be causing this differential behavior. Everything appeared to be in order.

Examined Web Server Logs: Reviewed the logs of our web server which hosts the QlikView reports. I couldn’t find any relevant errors that might provide a hint about this issue.

Expected Behavior:
I anticipated that when a report is available and set up in the QlikView Desktop application, and once the necessary permissions are granted, it should be consistently visible to all users via WebView. The inconsistency, especially when it was functional a day earlier, is quite perplexing.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to rectify this situation. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or could anyone provide a potential solution or troubleshooting step?

Thank you in advance!